# How to resize an image depending on div height and position selected of a cover photo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a cover profile photo that can be changed in my web app like facebook cover profile photo. I have implemented the function of repositioning the photo with `jquery UIdraggable` plugin and the upload  new photo function is implemented too.

for the repositioning this is how I proceeded:

- add a hidden input field on the form and save the latest `top` value
- when loading the page the `top` value is set to the saved value on the database.

for example this is a case on my PC screen with a top set to `top: -166px;` 
[image]

and this what I have on the mobile view :

[image]

every thing is working fine on my PC screen. the problem is that on small devices it's not the same position of the photo that I have repositionned rather there are some problems with dragging the photo on some small devices .

Do somebody have anidea how to correct this ? 
Or Is there any other plugin that do this thing ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use CSS instead of JS. You can set image as [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

property and config it with [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property

Comment: I set it but it disables the dragging function and the upload as well..

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple background property

```
 background: url("images/image-name.jpg")no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
```

Comment: I used it ,but  it disables the dragging function and the upload as well..

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead of background.

```
img {
  height: 200px; //your preferred height
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```